# Error: IllegalArgumentException - Spring security. Please give me a solution

Tags: spring-security, spelevaluationexception

I'm doing with spring security. When i browser `http://localhost:8080/rest/user/json/quypham` then occur following error:

> [WARNING] /rest/user/json/quypham java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Failed to evaluate expression 'ROLE_ADMIN'
>           at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evalua
>   teAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:15)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter
>   .vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:36)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter
>   .vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:18)
>           at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(Affi
>   rmativeBased.java:62)
>           at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterce
>   ptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInter
>
> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:
>   (pos 0): Property or field 'ROLE_ADMIN' cannot be found on object of
>   type 'org.s
>   pringframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot'
>   - maybe  not public?
>           at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.read
>   Property(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:215)
>           at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getV
>   alueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:85)
>           at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getV
>   alueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:78)
>           at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(Sp
>   elNodeImpl.java:114)
>           at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(
>   SpelExpression.java:105)
>           at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evalua

I think to have wrong somthing in file `userservice-servlet.xml`, please let me know.

Here file  `userservice-servlet.xml`

```
<security:http>
    <security:http-basic/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>            
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="datpham" password="Dat12345" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            <security:user name="hoaipham" password="Hoai12345" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Please don't post duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I have replace `spring-security-web` and `spring-security-config` version 4.0.3 to version 3.2.4.. Everything run ok, But i don't understand why ????